# TensorFlow: Import gzip mnist-dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently learning ML and walked through this 
[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/get_started/mnist/beginners)

Everything's fine and cool, but the mnist-import throws warnings and says the methods that are used are deprecated.

I don't know if I should "update" this, so that would be my first question, but I also want to import another dataset later (It will be train-images.gz etc. again)

So, what I need is a method that reads .gz-Datasets from a folder and imports them. I've read about `tf.data.Dataset`, but I think I didn't really get it or it's just not what I need.

Comment: isn't TF at r.1.9 now ? i also don't think you can have a "generic" import dataset: data are different based on the task you are elaborating...

Comment: I know - but I will use either a `emnist` or a `mnist` dataset. Both have the same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you mean, I actually tried it this morning (but failed), however I tried again: This seems to work (It's damn ugly and needs a workaround; but it works)

```
def _read32(bytestream):
  dt = np.dtype(np.uint32).newbyteorder('>')
  return np.frombuffer(bytestream.read(4), dtype=dt)[0]

def extract_images(f):
    print('Extracting', f.name)
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as bytestream:
        magic = _read32(bytestream)
        if magic != 2051:
            raise ValueError('Invalid magic number %d in MNIST image file: %s' %
                           (magic, f.name))
        num_images = _read32(bytestream)
        rows = _read32(bytestream)
        cols = _read32(bytestream)
        buf = bytestream.read(rows * cols * num_images)
        data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8)
        data = data.reshape(num_images, rows, cols, 1)
        assert data.shape[3] == 1
        data = data.reshape(data.shape[0],data.shape[1] * data.shape[2])
        data = data.astype(np.float32)
        data = np.multiply(data, 1.0 / 255.0)
        return data
def extract_labels(f):
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as bytestream:
        magic = _read32(bytestream)
        if magic != 2049:
            raise ValueError('Invalid magic number %d in MNIST label file: %s' %
                           (magic, f.name))
        num_items = _read32(bytestream)
        buf = bytestream.read(num_items)
        labels = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8)
        return labels

with gfile.Open("MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "rb") as f:
    train_images = extract_images(f)
with gfile.Open("MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "rb") as f:
    train_labels = extract_labels(f)
with gfile.Open("MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "rb") as f:
    test_images = extract_images(f)
with gfile.Open("MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "rb") as f:   
    test_labels = extract_labels(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation available at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials, applicable to TFv1.9, the canon way to import MNIST (as numpy arrays) using Tensorflow and avoiding deprecated Warnings  is:

```
 mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
 (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
 x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
```

Thus, from now on you should avoid the following:

- `mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")`
- `from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)`

Anyhow, if [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) is not an option, then maybe tweaking the function bellow will work:

```
def extract_images(f):
"""Extract the images into a 4D uint8 numpy array [index, y, x, depth].
Args:
   f: A file object that can be passed into a gzip reader.
Returns:
   data: A 4D uint8 numpy array [index, y, x, depth].
Raises:
   ValueError: If the bytestream does not start with 2051.
"""
print('Extracting', f.name)
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as bytestream:
   magic = _read32(bytestream)
   num_images = _read32(bytestream)
   rows = _read32(bytestream)
   cols = _read32(bytestream)
   buf = bytestream.read(rows * cols * num_images)
   data = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype=numpy.uint8)
   data = data.reshape(num_images, rows, cols, 1)
return data
```

Comment: Checked this already, but as far as I could see this will always download the dataset as a npz (or nzp?)-file from a server. I would neet them in a filer, or in the "standard-gzip-format", like the old method created